# Cannot deserialize user using redis (passport.js)

Tags: node.js, session, redis, passport.js

I was trying to implement redis into my already-working authentication section with passport.js. However when I use redis for some reason I get the following error:

Error: User not found
at /Documents/project/strategies/local.js:13:20
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

from this line:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
try {
    const user = await userRepository.getUserById(id);
    **if (!user) throw new Error('User not found');**
    delete user.dataValues.password;
    done(null, user.dataValues);
} catch (err) {
    done(err, null);
}
```

});

How Redis is implemented:

```
    // Redis
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    post: 6379,
    host: 'localhost',
});
// app.set('trust proxy', 1);
redisClient
    .connect()
    .then(console.log('Redis Connected!'))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
        resave: false,
        cookie: {
            secure: false, //true for production (https)
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4,
        },
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

EDIT:
I found out that this error only occurs when the cookie from a previous response is still saved. (passport logout does not remove the cookie, it only invalidates it)